# Output custom shape in ConsoleApplication - C#

Tags: c#, console-application

I have this shape and I want to output it to ConoleApplication Windows.

[image]

I have this code but it doesn't work as I need :

```
int i,j;

for(i=0;i<5;i++)

{

for(j=5-i;j>0;j--)

Console.WriteLine(" ");

for(j=0;j<=2*i;j++)

Console.WriteLine("*");

Console.WriteLine("\n");

}
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT : I am very sorry

Comment: Are you sure that you are programming in C#? it looks more like C to me. `it doesn't work as I need` In what way doesn't it work? What does it do? What error do you get? Why do you need to do this? Is it homework?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I was trying on both C# and C, Sorry again

Comment: You've edited to use `Console.WriteLine`; do you mean `Console.Write` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As everyone knows, everything Just Works™ when using LINQ... so, have you tried doing it with LINQ?

```
int n = 6;

var result = string.Join("\r\n", from i in Enumerable.Range(1, n)
                                 where i != 2
                                 let stars = Enumerable.Repeat('*', i)
                                 let indent = new string(' ', n - i)
                                 select indent + string.Join(" ", stars));

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

```
     *
   * * *
  * * * *
 * * * * *
* * * * * *
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
            for (j = 0; j <= 2 * i; j += 2)
            {
                printf("*");
                printf(" ");
                // or Console.Write("* ") if we are talking C#
            }
```

which writes the spaces between asterisks (plus a spare one; you could remove that if it is important).

Comment: Why did not you use `printf("* ")` once..?

Comment: @Betamoo - simple; I rarely (if ever) use C, and I couldn't be 100% sure that it would work, but the question itself showed usage for the versions shown.

Answer (score 0):

You just used `WriteLine` instead of `Write`

Here is the correct code:

```
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {

        for (j = 5 - i; j > 0; j--)
            Console.Write(" ");

        for (j = 0; j <= 2 * i; j++)
            Console.Write("*");

        Console.WriteLine();

    }
```

Comment: Isn't that lacking the spaces between the stars?

Comment: I think that is not what OP wanted to do... if so, he would try to print a space in his code...

Comment: Just trying to find what is wrong with his code... not re-inventing a new one!!